# SQL Server inserts fails silently

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have a stored procedure that inserts some rows into a table. Sometimes it seems to fail (can't find the new records) although I know the statements did execute. The code I use is bellow. After executing it I can find the relevant rows in the tbl_DebugLog table, but not on the tbl_WebSiteNotifications table.
I am using SQL Server 15.0.2. Also, this table is part of a merge replication.
What can cause this?

```
    insert into tbl_WebSiteNotifications(NotificationType, FileID, UserID, SubscriptionID, InsertionDate)
    select RequestType, FileID, UserID, SubscriptionID, DateRequested
        from #TempNotifications
        where UserID is not null


insert into tbl_DebugLog (LogDate, LogMessage, ServerName)
    select getdate(), 'FileID ' + format(FileID,'D') + N' for SubscriptionID ' + format (SubscriptionID,'D') + N' Inserted into tbl_WebSiteNotifications' + 
        ', NotificationType=' + format(RequestType,'D') + 
        ', UserID=' + format(UserID,'D') +
        ', InsertionDate=' + format(DateRequested,'dd-MM-yyyy'), 
        @@SERVERNAME
        from #TempNotifications
        where UserID is not null
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cause is most likely some constraint violation.

Why do not you see the error about it is a more difficult question. Are these two statements in different parts of SP surrounded by `try ... catch`? Is there a conditional logic which can call second statement without running first?

How do you run this stored procedure? Is it called from some client? Does it hide "irrelevant" warning messages?

Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your SP? Remove it, and run the SP from a client which prints all these "garbage" messages - they are very helpful in the cases like yours.

If you do not like messages from `nocount` option you can put a lot of `print "insert into tbl processed " + cast(@@rowcount as varchar(20))` between your statements.

Comment: Looks like indeed a constraint was violated. The procudre run every minute by the SQL agent, and in most cases was successfull so I missed the errors. Fixed it and will wait a few days to see if it realy soled the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An insert failing inside a procedure is not going to stop the procedure by default. If you want it to stop then set `XACT_ABORT` at the beginning of the procedure `SET XACT_ABORT ON` so the first insert will fail the procedure.

For example, this code will arrive to the select

```
SET XACT_ABORT off;

drop table if exists #temp
create table #temp ( intValue int not null, valueName varchar(100) )

insert into #temp values (1,'One')
insert into #temp values (null,'null')
insert into #temp values (2,'Two')

select * from #temp
```

And setting `XACT_ABORT ON`, will make it stop at the error in the second insert.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

drop table if exists #temp
create table #temp ( intValue int not null, valueName varchar(100) )

insert into #temp values (1,'One')
insert into #temp values (null,'null')
insert into #temp values (2,'Two')

select * from #temp
```

See [SET XACT_ABORT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql) in the documentation.